# Adding custom tab in redmine 2.0.3

Tags: tabs, redmine

I'd like to add custom tab to my redmine project which would be a static link to a webpage nested in IFRAME. I found [this thread](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/20?r=2165) and I thought that my problems are solved and I won't need to learn ruby.

But later I've noticed that plugin is almost 4 years old and not really compatible with current verison (I have 2.0.3 installed). When I already got it to run it still throws errors and plugin configuration page doesn't work correctly. Bottom line: I can't add any new tab.

Did someone experience similiar problem or maybe has a workaround/another method to add a simple custom tab/iframe to redmine without digging too much into source code?

Any help wold be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The actual plugin is up to date. Have a look at the projects git page.

https://github.com/jamtur01/redmine_tab

Comment: Yeah, I already managed to do that, I needed to merge with patch created by Ulle2 and fix some other minor issues. Maybe it's up to date but surely it's not without flaws.